# Using two XML files at once

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I have a problem with getting data from two XML files.
Right now i have a PHP file that gets the first file i need and sort of loads it in to my XSL file.
What i need is to use another XML file at the same time and, but im stuck.

Here is how my PHP and XSL files look right now.

PHP:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load("https://www.dnb.no/portalfront/datafiles/miscellaneous/csv/kursliste_ws.xml");

$elm = new DOMDocument();
$elm->load("weather.xsl");

$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$xslt->importStylesheet($elm);

echo $xslt->transformToxml($xml);
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" />
<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
<head>
<title>Sjekk været</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="weather.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Været og valutaen i Kanada:</h1>



<table>

  <tr>
    <th>Vær</th>
    <th>Norske kroner</th>
    <th>Kanadiske dollar</th>
  </tr>

    <xsl:for-each select="valuta/valutakurs[land='Canada']/overforsel">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>1 NOK</td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="kjop"/> CAD</td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>

</table>


</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `document()` [function in XSLT](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/func_document.asp) to refer to your second XML file:

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('second.xml')/node"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do you recomend that i add it in my PHP file? Or isn't that necessary?

Comment: you don't need to add it to the PHP file. Just make sure the file is present in the same directory where your primary XML file is.